# Node.js File Upload doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, request, postman

I need to post an image to an external service.

If I use a client like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) to test the upload manually it works perfectly.

I just have to make a `POST` and supply a body with `form-data` and a key `Picture` with the image. [image: POST request with Postman]

But it doesn't work if I'm posting from my node app. I'm using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module for handling requests.

```
const formData = { Picture: fs.createReadStream('./path/to/image') }

request.post({url: "http://example.com", formData: formData}, function(err, res, body) {
  console.log(body)
}
```

The log says `{"Code":400,"Exception":"The file failed to upload.}` Since it is an external service I can't get more information about the error.

I just need to replicate the request I make with postman.
How would you do it? I don't care about which module to use for the requests.

Comment: Your API usage seems fine, my guess is there is something else missing. Perhaps the server is checking for specific headers, such as 'User-Agent' or similar? Try duplicating the Postman request more exactly until you find what exactly is missing.

Answer (score 0):

When sending file consider using stream for the post action, for example:

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: "www.someurl.com"
};
const req = request(options, callback);
const form = req.form();
form.append('image', fs.createReadStream(file_path));
```

Is it possible that your are sending the file before the read action finished?